# QGIS 2.18 for mac: Processing NameError: global name 'QgsWKBTypes' is not defined

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

After installing the latest QGIS version for Mac (2.18.0), geoprocessing tools such as "Difference" and "Symmetrical Difference" are no longer working. Instead, the log window shows the following error message:

> 2016-11-14T14:28:43 2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
>               Traceback (most recent call last):
>                 File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
>                   self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>                 File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Difference.py", line 71, in processAlgorithm
>                   geomType = QgsWKBTypes.multiType(QGis.fromOldWkbType(layerA.wkbType()))
>               NameError: global name 'QgsWKBTypes' is not defined

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you send to trash QGIS old version before installing V.2.18.0?

Comment: Yes I completely removed the old version

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug in 2.18.0 which has been fixed meanwhile. Wait for 2.18.1.

Or install qgis2 from [homebrew](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/#how-do-i-install-these-formulae) with the `--devel` switch.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info! In that case I'll just wait for the new release.

Comment: By the way, for python errors in plugins it's always better to directly open a bug report (plugins all have a link to a bug_tracker in the plugin manager) - after checking if the same problem has not been reported before.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was not resolved with 2.18 release - it is specific to the "difference" function.  You can add the following to line 32 of the difference.py file, which for me was located at `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\qgis`:

from qgis.core import:

- QGis
- QgsFeatureRequest
- QgsFeature
- QgsGeometry
- QgsWKBTypes

Adding the `QgsWKBTypes` import allowed me to utilize the difference function.